# Get values of dropdown from Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

i'm new to VBA and i try to create a word document where the content of the document is shown based on the selection of two combo boxes.

i have an excel file with 3 columns, `server`, `version` and `content`

i want to fill one combo box with all the content of the column `server` and one with the content of `version`.

based on the selection underneath the content should be shown.

is there any way to achieve this or maybe do i need to change to a different solution?

Comment: Check if this can help .. https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/import_excel_list_into_word_dropdownlist.html

Comment: this was already very helpfull. i will just create multiple fields where i change the content of it based on the drop down selection. that will do the trick i think. maybe somebody else has more examples :)

Comment: Also, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxs42t1Vrz8